# Custom control design - opening edit dialog responsibility

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I have a custom Calendar control that is showing appointments in a chosen period of time.

I would like to add the ability to create/edit appointments. Appointment edit dialog (fields, save button, cancel button) should open when I click on a day.

Who should be responsible for opening the edit dialog?

1. Should the control be responsible for opening the dialog and have just `SaveCommand` and `EditedAppointment` property.
2. Or should it just expose commands/events for the user like `BeginEditCommand/DayClick event` and the user of my control would have to implement the dialog by herself (instead of just implementing Save command)? I think [DataGrid works that way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid?view=netframework-4.8#events)

Both solutions will work but which is better?

It's my first custom control in WPF so excuse me for a noob question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to say for definite without understanding where your control fits in the grand scheme of things, but to me editing and adding appointments sound like a part of the application rather than a simple control.

Controls tend to be good at one distinct thing, and reusable in many different scenarios, so need to be flexible. What if the app wanted to skin the appointment edit screen differently? Or display it in a completely different window? Or allow editing of multiple appointments at once?

You could always create another control for editing appointments that they are free to use if you want to make it easy for consumers, and they can plumb it in as they see fit. To be honest though, these things feel like they should be implemented as proper MVVM in the app rather than as custom controls.

Comment: what if I want to have 2 edit modes?: Quick edit mode and Full edit mode. I would also need to align the dialog to specific control inside my custom control. How would I access that control from outside? It seems like it should be a part of my control then.

Comment: Quick edit mode: would open a small dialog just next to edited appointment. I would need access to the control associated with that appointment using `ItemsContainerGenerator`